# Launch activity using pending intent when app running in background

Tags: android, kotlin

I have some problem how to launch **DetailActivity** using pending intent on a notification received
when the app is running in the background, it's always launching a **MainActivity** ( but when the app is running in the foreground its work fine )

Everybody can help me please and sorry for my bad English

> notificationIntent

```
val intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_MAIN
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

> PendingIntent

```
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 
    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
```

> manifest.xml

```
<application
            android:name=".helper.App"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_main_app"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_main_app"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
            tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
            tools:targetApi="m">

        <activity
           ndroid:screenOrientation="portrait"
           android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"
           android:name=".ui.activity.aduan.DetailActivity">
           <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
             android:value="kominfo.com.umat.ui.activity.main.MainActivity"/>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:name=".ui.activity.main.MainActivity"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: First confirm Did `onMessageReceived()` getting called when App is not Open ?

Comment: Yeah its called when app is not open

Comment: `onMessageReceived()` is this calling in background??

Comment: Yes buddy, its calling

Comment: Could be related to [Background Execution Limit](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services). Can you show your `onMessagereceived()`?

What kind of firebase messages do you receive ([data/notification message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive))? What's its priority?

Comment: What's this one val intent = Intent(this, AduanDetailActivity::class.java)?              
 In your manifest it's DetailActivity

Comment: Sorry its my mistake, but in real code is really the same

Answer (score 0):

you have set to your `DetailActivity` in `Manifest`

```xml
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    android:value="kominfo.com.umat.ui.activity.main.MainActivity"/>
```

This is the reason why your `DetailActivity` needs `MainActivity`

Also try to add following Flags to your Intent

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
```

and for `Notification`

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL
```

Comment: Change `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` to `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`